# Measuring application running time in CakePHP

Tags: php, performance, cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.0

In my production server I need to check running time of my application (I made in my local machine already)
But when I put microtime() between beforeFilter and afterFilter of my AppController I get very small results, say it `$runningTime=0.20` seconds.
But the time between writing address to my browser and seeing the output page is 100 times larger than runningTime.
I need to find out the leakage that makes my application slow. Is it possible to catch the time difference between I wrote address to browser and get the output on browser? Maybe I can find out the cause.
I found out `TIME_START` constant which seems like a wrapper for `microtime()`.

Comment: Look at the Network/Timing tab of the Inspector/Firebug tool in your browser. Most of the overhead is likely network delays, not the PHP script itself.

Comment: Yes. I also check it with pingdom tools. But I need something that makes it automatically from my code and logs to my server.

Comment: Your server can only log the execution time on the server. I'm saying the delays may be elsewhere, somewhere your server cannot log because it has nothing to do with the server.

Comment: How can I diagnose that the problem is network delay? (I can easily enter my website in nights and early morning hours)

Answer (score 0):

See below URL

[CakePHP 1.3: Measuring Page Execution Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719937/cakephp-1-3-measuring-page-execution-time)

Just in case anyone else is curious, I solved this by adding the following code to my layout.ctp. You could also do this in the controller and pass it in as a variable, which might be a little more classic MVC-friendly, but I wanted this on every page of the site without duplicating code in each controller

```
Page rendered in <?php echo round((getMicroTime() - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) * 1000) ?>ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

A running time of 0.2 seconds seems alright to me. If your script is running in 20 seconds, move te point where you start measuring more towards the start of the script and see the results.

Or .. use [xdebug profiling](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to see where your cpu cycles are going.